# returning value to beginning of php code

Tags: php, variables, return-value

I need help returning the value assigned to a variable to the beginning of the code, outside the statement.

so if a = 0 at the start, and then the value of a changes later because of a statement, I would like to be able to return the new value of a to the start of the page and replace the old value of a (a=0).

**CODE**

```
<?php
$a = 0;
echo $a; 

if (10>5){
$a = 5;
}

?>
```

so in this code when I start the page I should'nt see 0 anymore, it should be the new value

THANKS!

Comment: why not put condition first before echoing a

Comment: well I am building a ecommerce store and this is a very simplified version of the bigger code. I have my "$a" set to 0 at the start of the page, and when statements get executed it should go back to the start and change

Comment: you need to read OOP concepts, and learn how to use memcach, because php will completely forget what modification you've made once he finished his execution, Also you can take a look to **ANYEM** solution to learn how you can synchronize your variables

Comment: It is really hard to understand the question for me. Just shot to sky: $a = 0; while($a !=5) { echo $a; if () $a = 5;}

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

> I have my "$a" set to 0 at the start of the page, and when statements get executed it should go back to the start and change

**Solution:**

PHP executes statements sequentially, so it's not possible to *go back to the start*. Having said that, you can still achieve the desired result by controlling the flow of execution using [`goto`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php), like this:

```
<?php

    $a = 0;
    goto a;
    b:
    echo $a; // output 5
    goto c;

    a:
    if (10 > 5){
        $a = 5;
        goto b;
    }

    c:
    echo "<br />execution continues";

?>
```

Output:

```
5
execution continues
```

**Caution:** Don't use too much `goto` statements in your code because it'll make your code unreadable for future maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ob_start()

Hope this will help...

```
<?php

$a = 0;

ob_start();

echo $a;

$string = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

if (10 > 11) {
    $a = 5;
    echo $a;
} else {    
    echo $string;
}
```